# Alter Acquia Search Results

Tags: 7, search

I am using acquia search on D7 site. By default I get all the search results as Title, Teaser with search info at the bottom. I am trying to alter this results to add some of the field data.

Eg: Content type is a product and there is a Date of arrival field and Stock availability field for all the Product node.

Now how can I add these two fields as part of every result on search results page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache Solr Views](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) module. Add title, date and any other fields you want.

Comment: I did install this module.. and now I am lost. Because views is not providing any results for any of the fields.

Comment: Are you sure the search index works?

Comment: Yes, I have indexed all the products. And the normal search is working fine with facets, etc.

Comment: I get an error: Notice: Undefined property: apachesolr_views_query::$group_operator in apachesolr_views_query->build() (line 80 of /var/www/html/root/sites/all/modules/apachesolr_views/apachesolr_views_query.inc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_apachesolr_query_alter($query) to alter your results variable, if you're using [Apache solr views](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) and this error

> Notice: Undefined property: apachesolr_views_query::$group_operator in apachesolr_views_query->build() (line 80 of /var/www/html/root/sites/all/modules/apachesolr_views/apachesolr_views_query.inc‌​).

this means that you didn't use filters in your view.